# Can't alter UITabBarController badge in App Delegate when Tab Bar isn't root view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I would like to display a badge value on my tab bar everytime the below method gets called. The `NSLog` appears in the console, so the method works properly, but somehow the tab bar badge doesn't appears anyway. Am I doing it wrong? Or this part should be good and I missed something elsewhere?

```
// AppDelegate.m

- (void)pubnubClient:(PubNub *)client didReceiveMessage:(PNMessage *)message {

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

    UINavigationController *tabBarController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tab"];

    UITabBarController *tabController = (UITabBarController *)tabBarController;

    [[tabController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] tabBarItem].badgeValue = @"1";

    NSLog(@"SHOW BADGE");

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UINavigationController *tabBarController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tab"];
UITabBarController *tabController = (UITabBarController *)tabBarController;
```

This line (aside from the strange multiple casting) instantiates a *new* tab bar controller, it does not return a reference to the existing one. You should keep a reference to the existing tab bar controller instead of creating a new one.

Depending on your setup, you may be able to use the following instead:

```
UITabBarController *tabController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
```

Comment: How can I tell to the `tabController` that which is my existing tab bar controller? (when it's not the root view controller)

Comment: Yes, I checked it, but it works only when the tab bar controller is the root vc. Unfortunately in this situation the tab bar isn't a root view controller.

Comment: It's not difficult to traverse the view hierarchy, starting from the rootViewController. It's _your_ view hierarchy, you should know how it's organized.